# Overloading () operator for std::array gives: error C2039: '()' : is not a member of 'std::array<_Ty,_Size>'

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, operator-overloading

I have a piece of code which looks like this:

```
std::array<CPlayer,MAX_PLAYERS> Player;
#define Player(playerid) Player[playerid]
```

And use it then as follow:

```
Player(id).SomeMethod(some params);
```

But the definition is just ugly and I want to keep it as much as possible the C++ way, and std::array does have the [] operator but not the () operator so I tried adding this:

```
template < class T, size_t N > T& std::array<T, N>::operator()(int index)
{
    return this->at(index);
}
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
error C2039: '()' : is not a member of 'std::array<_Ty,_Size>'
```

What can I do about this? I'm clueless.

Comment: Why can't you just use `operator []`?

Comment: If you want to keep it as much like C++ as possible, use the proper indexing operator!

Comment: `#define Player(playerid) Player[playerid]` Is the only purpose of this to change `(` to `[`? Bit of a waste of time to write...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to add new members (functions or variables) to a class after it was defined.

I personally think that if it's an array, using `player[id].SomeMethod(some params);` work just as well as your suggestion.

Comment: And it's not permissible to overload operators for the standard library, even if they don't have to be members. Double whammy on that one.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you only want to access the array using function call `()` syntax (and in no other way) you can hide it as a local static variable in a function:

```
CPlayer& Player(size_t i)
{
    static std::array<CPlayer,MAX_PLAYERS> PlayerArray;
    return PlayerArray[i];
}
```

But no idea what you have against subscript `[]` expressions.

Comment: I have nothing against it, just looks nicer somehow xD